# Oh, não! Editaram minha pergunta!

Tags: debate, edição, proposta-para-faq

Um usuário novo chega no site, faz uma pergunta, e essa pergunta é editada por outra pessoa. O autor da pergunta estranha; afinal, ele está fazendo a pergunta, e quem melhor que ele próprio para explicar o seu problema? Em alguns casos, reclama, de diversas formas.

Isso é comum, e simples de entender: é contraintuitivo que um site de perguntas e respostas seja wiki. Onde é que o seu conteúdo pode ser editado por qualquer um? Num blog? Não. Rede social? Não. Fórum? Não. Yahoo! Respostas? Não. Wikipedia? Sim! Mas lá o conteúdo é (idealmente) factual. São verbetes. Em troca de precisão e detalhamento, aceitamos compartilhar a autoria. Mas numa pergunta, não sei de outro site que permita isso.

Acontece que funciona. Quanto mais clara uma pergunta, mais gente consegue responder, e mais gente com a mesma dúvida ela pode ajudar. Esse é o espírito do Stack Overflow e dos demais sites da rede. Perguntas claras, respostas excelentes, pouca redundância e conteúdo de qualidade ajudando o maior número possível de pessoas.

**Portanto, se alguém alterou a sua pergunta, isso é normal aqui no site. Por favor não se irrite, quem fez a edição está querendo ajudar. Só não vale alterar o que os outros querem dizer.**

Comment: Uma dúvida, para esse post ser ainda mais canônico, não seria legal fazê-lo válido para quando editarem as respostas tb? Pq do jeito que está é exclusivo para quando editarem as perguntas apenas. Acredito que o intuito desse post aqui é justamente usarmos ele de referencia futura para encaixar em um comentário explicando para os usuários que se sentirem ofendidos com edições, correto? PS: sim, eu sei, sou chato :P

Comment: Eu achei melhor focar em perguntas porque nelas é comum as edições serem mais drásticas. Talvez a parte das respostas caiba numa resposta aqui embaixo.

Comment: Hum, ok. Você tem razão. Valeu a explicação!

Comment: Intuitivamente, acho que 1 em cada 100 novos usuários reage negativamente a uma edição. O problema é que a reação costuma ser **bastante negativa** e *poucas vezes* é possível manter um diálogo civilizado. Sugerir a leitura do Tour adianta pouco e eventualmente um Meta post é criado onde a confusão termina em grosseria, votos negativos e a pergunta original deletada. Sim, sou pessimista quanto a esse 1%.

Comment: Foi exatamente um desses casos que me levou a postar isto, @brasofilo. É mais uma ajuda para tentar construir um diálogo civilizado. Se vai adiantar ou não, veremos.

Comment: Só eu que li esse "Oh, não!" do título com a voz das minhoquinhas do Worms Armagedon?

Comment: Profeta @brasofilo !

Comment: **Relacionado** : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eANH5f1ul7s

Comment: O legal que esse post também foi editado kkk O post fez jus ao objetivo que foi criado.

Comment: Em relação a edições, gostaria apenas de perguntar... E quando um moderador dá preferencia às suas edições e não  a edições de outras pessoas? Recusando a de todos e enviando a sua, sendo que a primeira edição foi feita igual a sua? Sempre que há mais edições entramos em uma fila e somos avisados sobre... Me deparo com esta situação direto aqui... Há como resolver? Ou preciso apenas me conformar?

Comment: @jakson poderia dar um exemplo concreto? Assim no geral não tenho como opinar

Comment: @bfavaretto, eu fico o dia inteiro no SOPT para poder ajudar enquanto trabalho. Durante o dia eu fico fazendo edição nos posts e tentando solucionar os problemas que aparecerem e que estou apto a opinar, porém, na semana passada, entre quinta e sexta me deparei com várias situações onde editei o POST da pessoa, a mensagem era que seria analisada, sendo assim, sei que eu sou o "1º da fila", porém, quando verificava, via que alguns que possuem os requisitos para aprovar ou reprovar faziam uma edição igual a que eu havia feito e em seguida recusavam a minha e aprovavam a deles.

Comment: @bfavaretto, isto não vem acontecendo de agora, vejo isto acontecer a muito mais tempo, infelizmente.

Answer (score 26):

Como já dito somos uma comunidade, acredito que a "pergunta" deixou bem claro o intuito da edição e quão ela pode ser benéfica para você mesmo se outro usuário editar. Porém irei falar sobre outro fator.

O Stack Overflow em Português é uma das comunidades do Stack Exchange, o funcionamento e a ideologia destas comunidades é justamente "qualquer usuário" poder "editar" e atuar como um tipo de "moderador" (sem o `♦︎`) para melhorar a comunidade e o entendimento das perguntas e respostas.

Também tem o intuito com este tipo de liberdade é ter um numero maior de "moderadores informais", para assim uma pessoa não ficar sobrecarregada com comunidades que recebem muitas perguntas/respostas por dia.

### Você pergunta:

Aonde você quer chegar com está conversa?

- Entende-se que com este tipo de liberdade o usuário que editou está atuando como o Stack Overflow pede para quem participa da comunidade, que ele colabore e ao editar é isto que ele está fazendo.

Mas a pergunta não é minha? Eu deveria ser informado?

- Sim a pergunta é "sua", mas ao participar das comunidades Stack Exchange, você está aceitando fazer contribuições sob a licença *creativecommons* (cc by-sa 3.0) como é descrito no rodapé do site:

  > © 2015 Stack Exchange Inc; contribuições de usuários com licença de cc by-sa 3.0 com atribuição necessária

Mas e se eu discordar de uma edição, então não posso fazer nada?

- Pode sim, assim como o usuário que editou a sua pergunta, se você achar que a edição dele "distorce" o sentido da sua pergunta ou não por "vandalismo", então você também pode editar a sua própria pergunta ou fazer o chamado `rollback`.

Acaso a pessoa que editou persistir na atitude, recomendo não discutir com ele, deixe a edição feita por ele e abra uma questão no http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com com as tags [pergunta-específica](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pergunta-espec%c3%adfica) e [edição](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/edi%c3%a7%c3%a3o) e explique o problema, existem punições em alguns casos, para atitudes que podem não ser legais para a comunidade, claro que o caso é analisado primeiro.

Se tiver sido um ato de vandalismo na pergunta/resposta, delete-a e crie uma pergunta no meta como sugerido, pois usuários com maior pontuação e moderadores♦︎ podem ver o que ocorreu, mesmo estando deletada, assim que o problema for resolvido, basta desfazer o deletar.

> Note que em alguns casos você é informado de uma edição, mas isto varia com o tipo de usuário que editou, no caso de usuário com uma pontuação maior e privilégio adquirido com está pontuação, ele pode editar sem que você confirme.

---

### A licença cc by-sa 3.0

> Note: o texto descrito abaixo é apenas para leitura e um entendimento rápido, porém não substitui o texto da licença que se encontra aqui: http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/legalcode

Está licença permite os usuários editarem pelos seguintes motivos descritos na licença:

Você é livre para:

- Compartilhar — Copiar e redistribuir
- Adaptar — Modificar, transformar e criar algo sobre o material fornecido sob ela
  para qualquer finalidade, inclusive comercial.

O "licenciador" não pode revogar essas liberdades contanto que você siga os termos da licença:

- Atribuição - Você deve dar crédito adequado, fornecer um link para a licença, e indicar se as mudanças foram feitas. Você pode fazê-lo de qualquer forma razoável, mas não em qualquer forma que sugira que o licenciador concorde com você ou seu uso.
- Compartilhamento pela mesma licença - Se você modificar, transformar ou criar algo em cima do material, você deve distribuir suas contribuições sob a mesma licença que o original.
- Não há restrições adicionais - Você não pode aplicar termos legais ou medidas tecnológicas que legalmente restringem os outros de fazer qualquer coisa a licença permite.

### Consideração pessoal

Se você discorda do modelo do Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange então considere ler a área de https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/editing como sugeriu o @PapaCharlie, lá está escrito algo como:

> Editar é importante para manter as perguntas e respostas claras,
>   relevantes e atualizadas. Se não se sente confortável com a ideia de
>   que suas contribuições sejam editadas de modo colaborativo por outros
>   usuários confiáveis, este site não é para você.

Por favor não se sinta ofendido, apenas procure ter a mente mais aberta e verá que o modelo apresentado nas comunidades do Stack Exchange anda demonstrando ser um grande agregador de conteúdo de qualidade e fonte de pesquisa muito útil.

Sinceramente eu passava muito mal com os fóruns, cheios de perguntas repetitivas, desorganização e conteúdos interessantes que ficavam no limbo. Para mim o sistema de fórum um dia foi bom, mas hoje é obsoleto. Se der uma chance ao Stack Overflow, garanto que logo não irá querer outro tipo de comunidade.

Answer (score -5):

Já passei por isso e realmente a maioria quer ajudar, mas já ouve casos comigo de responder uma pergunta, porém o autor alterou o titulo e a pergunta e minha resposta ficou toda fora de contexto e resultou em vários votos negativo.

Tenho que dizer que me decepcionei com o stack algumas vezes, as vezes quando eu ia fazer uma pergunta muitas vezes alguém falava "Você sabe o que é google"? ou simplesmente desativavam a minha pergunta com a desculpa: "No intuito de melhorar a comunidade" até que chegaram um ponto que minha conta ficou com 6 meses de block, isso me fez refletir? se afinal ninguém nasce sabendo, e muitas vezes você não acha suas respostas no google e nem em livros então de que adianta uma comunidade com o propósito de ajudar outros programadores e fornecer uma troca de conhecimento quando os próprios membros não permitem? Não adianta nada, mas é claro não querendo generalizar pois ainda assim no geral essa comunidade é bem útil, e por algum motivo os programadores brasileiros são mais receptivos quando se trata de algo que você desconhece completamente (talvez por que o Brasil é carente de programadores então os membros tentam se ajudar) e acabam lhe ajudando a sanar suas questões.

Comment: Mas a pergunta não é sobre comentários ou com perguntas com problema de qualidade, a postagem aqui é antiga, de 2014 e fala sobre edições das postagens e qual o intuito, acho que você se perdeu em algum momento ao ler a pergunta. Não estou criticando, só estou tentando lhe orientar o propósito. A não ser que eu tenha entendido algo de errado.