# Quais as diferenças entre Stack Exchange, Yahoo Resposta e outros sites de perguntas e respostas?

Tags: debate, comunidade

Creio que as principais diferenças não estão na estrutura e organização dos sites que aqui é muito superior (de fato Yahoo podeira ter um infra-estrutura melhor), mas no que acontece com a comunidade.

De onde vem a motivação dos usuários da rede Stack? Como a lógica das comunidades Stack produzem conteúdo alta qualidade?

Seguindo esse enfoque.
 
Quais as diferenças entre Stack Exchange, Yahoo Resposta e outros sites de perguntas e respostas?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Em resumo:

1. <strike>Yahoo Respostas</strike> ou *Quora* são sites de perguntas e respostas para diversos assuntos.
2. *Stack Exchange* não é um site de *Q&A*, ele é uma rede de sites.
3. Sites dentro da rede Stack Exchange como:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com
- https://superuser.com
- https://webmasters.stackexchange.com
- https://askubuntu.com
- https://apple.stackexchange.com

São sites de assuntos específicos, o sistema de [*gamefication usado nos sites da rede Stack Exchange*](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-gamification/) também é um pouco mais avançado, possuímos edições colaborativas, além disso contamos com uma área em cada site chamada "META" que visa:

- Receber sugestões
- Relatar bugs (use a tag [bug](/questions/tagged/bug))
- Tirar duvidas sobre o site especifico da rede, tanto sobre funcionalidades quanto comportamento
- Mediar problemas e perguntas ou respostas existentes no site principal (geralmente usamos a tag [pergunta-específica](/questions/tagged/pergunta-espec%c3%adfica))

**De onde vem a motivação dos usuários da rede Stack? Como a lógica das comunidades Stack produzem conteúdo alta qualidade?**

Acredito que seja devido a estes quatro fatores:

1. O [*gamefication*](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-gamification/), que principalmente pra quem está iniciando é uma coisa que ajuda a incentivar
2. O site tratar apenas um assunto especifico (cada site tem um "escopo definido")
3. Os usuários atuam como uma *especie de moderadores não oficiais* dependendo do nível que ele esta, assim podendo editar e fechar perguntas e respostas com problemas, assim ajudando a melhorar a qualidade conforme a experiencia (ver privilégios **https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges**)
4. As edições colaborativas, veja esta pergunta **[Oh, não! Editaram minha pergunta!](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2212/3635)** para mais detalhes
5. [Fila de analise de conteúdo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review), que é um centro de ferramentas que usando votos nelas definimos o que mantem aberto ou reabre, o que fecha, o que precisa de edição, etc.

Comment: Ótima resposta, apenas a motivação que não pode ser generalizada. Eu por exemplo, não ligo para pontos, ranking e tal, só ligo para ajudar quem eu vejo que precisa de ajuda, como já me ajudaram inúmeras vezes. Muitos outros tem outras motivações. Mas acho que posso dizer, que o "gamefication" é um dos principais motivos de muitos

Comment: Não sei bem como funcionam edições no y!a e quora, mas pra mim a melhor característica da SE é a edição colaborativa e a curadoria coletiva dos conteúdos.

Comment: @bfavaretto com certeza, realmente é uma das melhores coisas dos sites da rede, vou editar :)

Comment: Concordo com o bfavaretto, eu diria na verdade que essa é a principal diferença dos sites da SE. A edição colaborativa e a moderação pela própria comunidade fazem com que os sites tenho quase sempre conteúdo de altíssima qualidade, e que com o passar do tempo tende apenas a melhorar. Isso nem sempre ocorre no Quora, e no Y! tem muito mais porcaria e spam do que coisa útil.

Comment: @Molx tá adicionado na resposta =) Cê viu? Então até que o Quora é melhorzinho, mas o Y! é mais uma zona de trolls que qualquer outra coisa :/

Comment: a diferenca é a qualidade e o foco

Comment: @AndréSilveiraMachado obrigado pela opinião, então diga quais os motivos que na rede Stack Exchange levam ao foco e qualidade?

Comment: Muita gente que sabe de verdade, já no yahoo é um toma lá da cá, e aqui tem controle das respostas, lá nao, = qualidade

Comment: Sim @AndréSilveiraMachado não discordo, só que a pergunta foi *Como a lógica das comunidades Stack produzem conteúdo alta qualidade?*, ou seja já sabemos que os sites da SE tem qualidade, agora o que a minha resposta tenta explicar é como o funcionamento gera essa qualidade, entende? =) ... Vou aproveitar e detalhar a resposta, até mais